# Excel: VLOOKUP that returns true or false?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

In Excel we have the `VLOOKUP` function that looks for a value in a column in a table and then returns a value from a given column in that table if it finds something. If it doesn't, it produces an error.

Is there a function that just returns true or false depending on if the value was found in a column or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could wrap your VLOOKUP() in an IFERROR()

Edit: before Excel 2007, use `=IF(ISERROR()...)`

Comment: So I'd just do =IF(ISERROR(); "not found"; "found") or something like that?

Comment: Yes. `=IF(ISERROR(Vlookup(...)),"not found","found")` keeping all the important bits inside the Vlookup function.

Comment: Or even =IF(ISERROR(Vlookup(...)),FALSE,TRUE) to give the True/False of your original request

Comment: COUNTIF is a MUCH faster solution.

Answer (score 7):

You still have to wrap it in an ISERROR, but you could use `MATCH()` instead of `VLOOKUP()`:

> Returns the relative position of an
>   item in an array that matches a
>   specified value in a specified order.
>   Use MATCH instead of one of the LOOKUP
>   functions when you need the position
>   of an item in a range instead of the
>   item itself.

Here's a complete example, assuming you're looking for the word "key" in a range of cells:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("key",A5:A16,FALSE)),"missing","found")
```

The `FALSE` is necessary to force an exact match, otherwise it will look for the closest value.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a COUNTIF ! Much faster to write and calculate than the other suggestions.

---

EDIT:

> Say you cell A1 should be 1 if the value of B1 is found in column C and otherwise it should be 2. How would you do that?

I would say if the value of B1 is found in column C, then A1 will be positive, otherwise it will be 0.  Thats easily done with formula: `=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$15,B1)`, which means: count the cells in range `C1:C15` which are equal to `B1`.

You can combine `COUNTIF` with `VLOOKUP` and `IF`, and that's MUCH faster than using 2 lookups + ISNA.   `IF(COUNTIF(..)>0,LOOKUP(..),"Not found")`

A bit of Googling will bring you tons of [examples](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/count-if.htm).

Comment: Could you give an easy example? Say you cell A1 should be 1 if the value of B1 is found in column C and otherwise it should be 2. How would you do that?

Comment: The question was *is there a function that just returns true or false depending on if the value was found in a column or not?*. To which `COUNTIF` is the simplest answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

We've always used an

```
if(iserror(vlookup,"n/a",vlookup))
```

Excel 2007 introduced IfError which allows you to do the vlookup and add output in case of error, but that doesn't help you with 2003...

Comment: except that my answer is for xl2003, with some additional information about xl2007

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(lookup value,table array,column no,FALSE)),"FALSE","TRUE")
```

Comment: -1 for providing the same approach as an existing answer  - 3 years afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

ISNA is the best function to use.  I just did.  I wanted all cells whose value was NOT in an array to conditionally format to a certain color.

=ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$D,2,FALSE))